# Protractor Extension of ElementFinder

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to extend the ElementFinder of Protractor with a few additional methods.
I am doing this exactly the same way I also extended other classes, where it works without any problem.
In a separate file called 'protractor-extension.ts', both the module declaration and the method implementation is contained:

```
declare module 'protractor/built/element' {
  export interface ElementFinder {
      safeClick() : Promise<void>;
  }
}

(protractor.ElementFinderas any).safeClick= function () {
  const _self = this as protractor.ElementFinderas ;
   return await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(self), 5000)
      .then(function() {
          return self.click(); //if found
      }, function() {
          console.error(`Element is not clickable`); //error
      });
}
```

This file is then imported in the .spec file where the safeClick() is used, with  "import './extensions/protractor-extension.ts';"

The function is recognized, and I immediately get it in code-completion when using it on any ElementFinder.

The problem: During runtime I always get "Failed: myButton.safeClick is not a function"

As I said, if I replace the whole example 1:1 with the moment.js example, it works. So it seems to be related to the ElementFinder in protractor?
All existing posts related to this topic also suggest to do exactly what I have done, but most of them are outdated (<2 years old).

I appreciate any hint that leads me to the right solution.

EDIT:
Here is how the extension methods are used:

1) In the page object, the elements are declared

```
export class AdminPage {

  /*  ELEMENTS  */
  public userTable =   element(by.id('userTable'));
  public unlockBtn = element(by.id('unlockBtn'));    
}
```

2) In the test (.spec file), the extension method is used

```
it('unlock button should disappear after click', async () => {
  await this.adminPage.unlockBtn.safeClick();
  expect(this.unlockBtn.isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
});
```

-> .safeClick() is autocompleted when writing "this.adminPage.unlockBtn.."
-> .safeClick() is not recognized during runtime and throws an error

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use `element()` and `element.all()` in your script to declare web element on page.

`element` or `all` is instance of class `ElementFinder`, and both are created at very beginning of running test case.

If your above code executed behind of the creation of `element` and `all`, `element` and `all` won't includes the `safeClick()`

Following is protractor init procedure:

```
lib/cli.ts https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/cli.ts#L242

 --> lib/launcher.ts initFn()

  --> lib/launcher.ts createNextTaskRunner()

   --> lib/taskRunner.ts run()  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/launcher.ts#L222

    --> lib/runner.ts run()    https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/runner.ts#L334

     --> lib/runner.ts createBrowser()       https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/browser.ts#L316

      --> lib/brower.ts ProtractorBrowser()  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/runner.ts#L237
          // element created in this method

     --> lib/runner.ts setupGlobals_()     https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/runner.ts#L335
          // setup element, all, $$, browser in global space
```

As I learned, protractor did not provide something like hooks to enable user to do something prior to `lib/runner.ts createBrowser()`.  If have, you can add your code in the hook.

Comment: I added how I am using the methods, for me it looks like it should be, but maybe I am missing something. How does the creation of the ElementFinder interact with its function extension (I found out its called module augmentation in Typescript)?

Comment: Where did you define the `safeClick()`? In separate fil, in protractor.conf.js, in pageobject file, in test case file?  When/where you load it?

Comment: Its a separate file called 'protractor-extension.ts', where both the module declaration and the method implementation is contained. This file is then imported in the .spec file where the safeclick is used, with  "import './extensions/protractor-extension.ts';"  To verify that I am correctly defining everything i did the same thing for another module, moment js, using the same file locations. there it worked.

Comment: As i said above, to archive your goal, you have to make `protractor-extension.ts` to be imported prior to the `element` and `all` created.  The reason of same things in moment.js work is that it's not a part of protractor and `ElementFinder` did not depends on it. If depends, same thing in memont.js should not work too.

Comment: So in short, because of the lack of hooks in protractor, its not possible to initialize ElementFinder module augmentations before protractor creates element & all.

Comment: I'm not good at JavaScript prototype. Maybe you can give a try add `saveClick` to ElementFinder or element's prototype in protractor.conf.js  'onPrepare'

Comment: Ok I'll try it!