# Protractor Extension method for element Finder

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to extend the ElementFinder of Protractor with a few additional methods. I am doing this exactly the same way I also extended other classes, where it works without any problem. In a separate file called 'protractorElement.Extend.ts', both the module declaration and the method implementation is contained:

```
declare module 'protractor/built/element' {

    export interface ElementFinder {
        sendText(text: string) : promise.Promise<void>;
        safeClick() : promise.Promise<void>;
        hasClass(clazz: string) : Promise<boolean>;
    }
}


ElementFinder.prototype.safeClick = async function () {
    let self = this;
    try {
        await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(self), 5000);
        return self.click(); //if found
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(`Element is not clickable`); //error
    }
}

export *  from 'protractor';

When calling this in my test file - 
   affirmationPage.btnNext.safeClick();
```

I get this error - 
  - Failed: affirmationPage.btnNext.safeClick is not a function

I read somewhere I need to initialise this on my conf.js file OnPrepare method . I am not sure how to do it .

Comment: Look my answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239852/protractor-extension-of-elementfinder/59260601#59260601

Comment: Yes , I saw that but there are two things mentioned - 1) it is not possible and 2) you mention that to include in onprepare function of conf.js. - How to do that on conf.js - Onprepare - do I need to write only the method. An elaborated reply will be appreciated.